# Add hyperlink to citations

Tags: cross-referencing, citing

I am trying to cite a part of the bibliography or a formula in a text. I have a number which I want to cite in the text, but there is no link on the number on which to click and go to the formula/bibliography.
How could I change that?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer - just used the package 
`\usepackage{hyperref}`.